# Can't add taxonomy term to node?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

This code saves the taxonomy term, but it doesn't add it to the node.
What is the problem?

```
             $node = new stdClass(); // Create a new node object
            $node->type = "article"; // Or page, or whatever content type you like
            node_object_prepare($node); // Set some default values
            $node->language = en; // Or e.g. 'en' if locale is enabled
            $node->title = $title;
            $node->field_image['und'][0] = (array)$file;
            $node->uid = '1'; // UID of the author of the node; or use $node->name

            $tags = explode(",",$sended_tags);
            $vid = 1;

            $term = new stdClass();
            $term->name = $tags[0];
            $term->vid = $vid;
            taxonomy_term_save($term);


            $node->taxonomy[] = $term;

            node_save($node);
```

Comment: It appears you are coding for Drupal 7, so you'll need to use a field for your taxonomy term. That will already be defined in your content type.

Comment: Yes, I am. What is the code for the field_tags?

Comment: See the answer posted by @Alexander.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
if ($foo = taxonomy_get_term_by_name($term_name)) {
      $foo_keys = array_keys($foo);
      $node->your_taxonomy_field_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][]['tid'] = $foo_keys[0];  
    }
    else {
      $node->your_taxonomy_field_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][] = array (
        'vid' => 1,
        'tid' => 'autocreate',
        'name' => $term_name,
        'vocabulary_machine_name' => 'machine_name'
      );
```

Comment: Thanks! This works, even though I don't know why. :D